# dataview rowfilter in Loop

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

```
        DataTable Table = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;
        try
        {
            row = Value.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < Value.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TableNm = new DataView(DB.Tables[1]);
                TableNm.RowFilter = "name = " + "'" +""+Value.Rows[i][0].ToString()+"" + "'" + "";
                row[i] = (TableNm.ToTable()).Rows;
            }
            Table.Rows.Add(row);
```

For The Above I am Trying to Filter Multiple value and Bind or add row in data table But it's not working any suggestion for dataview rowfilter in for loop 
where every Rowfilter return only one row every time

Comment: I have much more difficult questions about this piece of code. Please post the complete code.

Comment: Please try to formulate your questions in a coherent way.

Comment: It's as Simple 
let 
as You have 20 record
and you want any 5 record with in 20 record so you have to Filter data view 5 time than add those row to any data table or what aver 
so if i try to do this how can we used to add row after every filter in to data table ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a real problem you can add Dynamically column first than try  row.add(row item arry) instant of row.add()

just like

```
 DataTable Table = new DataTable();
    DataRow row;
    try
    {
//Add column here

        row = Value.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < Value.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TableNm = new DataView(DB.Tables[1]);
            TableNm.RowFilter = "name = " + "'" +""+Value.Rows[i][0].ToString()+"" + "'" + "";
            row[i] = (TableNm.ToTable()).Rows;
        }
        Table.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
```